# Link proxy settings to particular wifi network

Tags: 12.04, wireless, network-manager, proxy

Is there a way to automatically set proxy settings based on which wifi network you are connected to?

Answer (score -1):

You might want to check out transparent proxying. Its very convenient.

[Transparent proxying](http://www.benzedrine.cx/transquid.html)

Comment: Thanks. I'm already using a local proxy server to handle CNTLM (Microsoft) authentication for me. But I still need a way to enable and disable the proxy automatically depending on whether I'm on campus or not (my University uses a proxy server for all internet traffic). I'm not sure how a transparent proxy would help me solve this problem. It would need to change its upstream proxy based on the wifi network I'm connected to.